# iOS - UIView. What are the limitations of using drawRect to do data retrieval?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks, drawrect, nsurlconnectiondelegate

For my iOS app I am implementing a "lazy" data loading scheme that is almost there, but not quite. I override my `UIView` subclasses `drawRect` method thusly:

The overridden `drawRect` method

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[self.featureSource featuresForInterval:interval completionHandler:^(NSData *data) {

    // Create list of features from retrieved data
    FeatureList *features = [[[FeatureList alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

    // Render features
    [self.currentRenderer renderInContext:context rect:rect featureList:featureList;
}];
```

A trivial renderer that paints red:

```
// A trivial renderer that paints red
- (void)renderInContext:(CGContextRef)context rect:(CGRect)rect featureList:(FeatureList *) featureList {

    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

}
```

The feature retrieval method ...

```
- (void)featuresForInterval:(FeatureInterval *)interval completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *))completionHandler
```

... retrieves data from the cloud using `NSURLConnection`'s asynchronous delegate method callbacks. In the data completion method `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` I call the `completionHandler` shown above that does the actual rendering.

Problem. This successfully retrieves data but when the rendering method is called nothing is drawn. I get the following messeges on the console:

```
2013-01-08 21:02:34.417 IGV[49732:f803] -[URLDataLoader connection:didReceiveResponse:] [Line 248] data 0
2013-01-08 21:02:34.417 IGV[49732:f803] -[URLDataLoader connection:didReceiveData:] [Line 260] data 998
2013-01-08 21:02:34.419 IGV[49732:f803] -[URLDataLoader connection:didReceiveData:] [Line 260] data 2446
2013-01-08 21:02:34.423 IGV[49732:f803] -[URLDataLoader connection:didReceiveData:] [Line 260] data 3845
2013-01-08 21:02:34.424 IGV[49732:f803] -[URLDataLoader connectionDidFinishLoading:] [Line 275] data 3845
Jan  8 21:02:34 new-host-5.home IGV[49732] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Jan  8 21:02:34 new-host-5.home IGV[49732] <Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
Jan  8 21:02:34 new-host-5.home IGV[49732] <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
Jan  8 21:02:34 new-host-5.home IGV[49732] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your request is asynchronous. This means that drawRect: finishes before the request is done.
Consider creating a property/variable on your view class and implement drawRect: like the following:

```
if(self.features) {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.currentRenderer renderInContext:context rect:rect featureList:featureList;
} else {
    [self.featureSource featuresForInterval:interval completionHandler:^(NSData *data) {

        // Create list of features from retrieved data
        self.features = [[[FeatureList alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, for context everything is kicked off by a [myView setNeedsDisplay]. So a client of MyView needn't think about whether features are available to render. Let me see if I got this: with your example regarding self.features, for the non-nil case [myView drawRect] calls a renderer, cool, got it. For the nil case [myView drawRect] calls the async data load which at completion calls setNeedDisplay which notifies the runloop to call [myView drawRect] at some point in the future which eventually calls the renderer. Have I got that right? Neat.

Comment: Yep this is what i intended :) Only you should gracefully handle errors (what if network isn't enabled) > maybe an additional if condition around -setNeedsDisplay

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[yourView setNeedsDisplay]` to make it render. iOS sets up the `CGContextRef` for you during the run loop so that there is something valid when you call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. Calling `[yourView setNeedsDisplay]` will start that process, you don't need to call `drawRect` directly.

You might want to read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) for more details on the mechanics.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that this is kicked off by a call of the form [myView setNeedsDisplay]